# Is createDatastore destructive?

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

If I use the [`Morphia.createDatastore()`](http://mongodb.github.io/morphia/1.3/javadoc/org/mongodb/morphia/Morphia.html#createDatastore-com.mongodb.MongoClient-java.lang.String-) method, and the `name` I pass denotes an already existing Mongo database with an object in it, what is the expected behavior?  I hope that it is not to delete the existing database.

(I am trying to debug a strange interaction between two Mongo-interacting programs.  One uses Morphia; the other does not.  The second program writes an object into the database.  The first program saves two objects into the database.  The first program then reports that the total number of objects in the database is two, not three.  Neither program ever reports that the database is missing, i.e. all insertions work fine.)

Answer (score 1):

it is not destructive.  I would verify that all your database and collection names match.

Comment: Hi! Yes, they do.  That's what is particularly weird about all this.

Comment: Tangentially related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48160098/what-is-the-intended-behavior-of-datastore-save-when-handed-an-iterable-of-obj/48160246