# What is the intended behavior of Datastore.save() when handed an Iterable of objects?

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I am debugging a bizarre situation involving MongoDB and two programs.

The MongoDB installation in question is initially empty and is a toy deployment.

There are two programs.  One uses Morphia.  The other does not.

The non-Morphia-using program inserts a record into a `Service` collection in a `foo-bar` database like so:

```
mongo << EOF
db.getSiblingDB("foo-bar").getCollection("Service").replaceOne( {
  "service_name" : "argle-bargle"
}, {
  "_id" : "argle-bargle",
  "className" : "com.foo.Service",
  "service_name" : "argle-bargle",
}, {
  "upsert" : true
} )
EOF
```

The write is acknowledged:

```
MongoDB shell version v3.4.6
connecting to: mongodb://aura-mongodb:27017/
MongoDB server version: 3.4.6
{
    "acknowledged" : true,
    "matchedCount" : 0,
    "modifiedCount" : 0,
    "upsertedId" : "argle-bargle"
}
bye
```

The Morphia-using program does this:

```
final MongoClient client = // ...
final Morphia morphia = new Morphia();
morphia.mapPackage("com.foo");
final Datastore dataStore = morphia.createDatastore(client, "foo-bar");
assert dataStore != null;
dataStore.ensureIndexes();
```

…followed by:

```
final Collection<com.foo.Service> services = // ...collection of size 2...
this.dataStore.save(services);
```

There should now be three items in the database.  There are not.

Connecting with `mongo` and getting ahold of the `Service` collection in the `foo-bar` database and issuing `find()` shows there to be two (the result of the Morphia-using program's operation).

I HOPE that if I had 20,000 records in that collection that a `save(collectionOf2Items)` would not delete 19,998 of them!

So then: is `save` destructive when handed an `Iterable`?  Any other suggestions on how to debug this baffling problem are greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should set profiling level to 2 to log all operations in your database. See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.setProfilingLevel/
Then you can at least see what operations the database receives.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without any code but if the ID's of the items match calling `save()` will simply update the existing item.

From [Morhpia Quick Tour](http://mongodb.github.io/morphia/1.0/getting-started/quick-tour/)

> Updating data in MongoDB is as simple as updating your Java objects and then calling datastore.save() with them again.

Edit:
For debugging it might be worthwhile to try manually setting the ID fields to an ID you know is not already in use.

Comment: Thanks. In this case the collection being saved is an initial dump into an empty database, so the save() should translate into two inserts.  I've traced through some of the Morphia source code and it sure looks like after it's done with mapping concerns (mine are trivial) save just does an insert.  No destructive behavior.  This is really weird.

Comment: Also in case it matters this is a single node toy mongodb deployment, nothing fancy.

Comment: If you could update the original post with a bit more of the Morphia code I may be able to update my answer.

Comment: Post updated.  ids are deliberately non-numeric and known to be unique.  Specifically, none of the `Service`s in the collection of size 2 have `_id`s or `name`s equal to each other or `argle-bargle`.

Comment: If the Morphia-using program runs first, then the non-Morphia program's insertion works fine and is picked up by the Morphia-using program.  If the Morphia-using program runs second, as described above, then the insertion is acknowledged and successful, but its results do not appear in the database.

Comment: can you put together a small project on github or wherever for me to see this in action?

Comment: If I get time.  In the meantime, suppose the non-Morphia program does not explicitly create the database or the collection.  Could that be the culprit?  I was under the impression mongo silently created these things just-in-time.

Comment: What happens if you do the insert with the non-Morphia program and then connect with the Morphia program, without actually performing the insert?

Comment: @evanchooly it gets weirder.  I've refactored things so that I'm not using the "write to the side" mongo connection at all.  That is, now I am using Morphia in both cases.  Mongo is acknowledging the write.  But the results are still not showing up.  This is in a Docker and Kubernetes ecosystem.  Is it possible for a write to be acknowledged but not to actually happen?  If so, how would I discover that this has happened?